# jQuery UI accordion open after loading jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery UI accordion for the first time and I have a question:
How I can delay the opening after all Ajax data is loaded?

Here is the accordion code:

```
var ac = $("#accordion").accordion(
    { 
        active: false, 
        event: false, 
        autoHeight: false, 
        navigation: false 
    }, 
    { header: "table" }
);
```

I know I can start open animation in this function:

```
$(".SearchResults").load(
    url, 
    { input: id }, 
    function () { 
        hideProgress(); 
    }
);
```

After hideProgress it will run. How I can start opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the accordion initialisation to the callback, after `hideProgress()`, like this:

```
$(".SearchResults").load(
    url, 
    { input: id }, 
    function () { 
        hideProgress(); 
        var ac = $("#accordion").accordion(
            { 
                active: false, 
                event: false, 
                autoHeight: false, 
                navigation: false 
            }, 
            { header: "table" }
        );
    }
);
```